# C#/Android Compatible Compression Algorithm

Tags: c#, android, compression

I have a lot of plain-text content (English). I have a C# tool for creating the content, and it will be consumed in an Android app.

I need, therefore, to know my options for compression algorithms. What library can I use to compress/decompress, where I can compress in C# and decompress in Java?

I'm looking at probably 1-2MB of uncompressed text (at least), so it's definitely worth it to compress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to zip in C# using something like [this](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) and unzip with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html).  GZIP format should do the trick.

Comment: GZip is a standardized algorithm? I thought the implementation details vary based on the platform.

Comment: The deflate algorithm used by gzip is at least a de facto standard, and should work fine across different platforms.

Comment: Gzip is a file format with a DEFLATE payload, a 10 byte header and an 8 byte footer as well as some optional data.  If your libraries output bytes in gzip format, they should compress and decompress across platforms just fine.

Comment: One more thing, it's a good idea when testing to use gzip or another compression tool to verify that a file is in the expected format.